# How could I give access to private variables to another class but not to the programmer?

Tags: c#

I'm not even quite sure how to word my question, so I'll just show by example. I want the equivalent of:

```
public class OuterClass 
{
   public InnerClass DoStuff(InnerClass this_class) 
     {
          this_class.number = 5;
          return this_class;
     }


   public class InnerClass
     {
          private int number = 0;
     }

}
```

I have an internal class, which the programmer can set some variables and such in, but it also has some internal variables which they should never touch or need to know about. The outer class works with the instances of the internal class, and it needs to know about these internal variables. I can think of a few more convoluted ways to go about what I want, but I'm curious, is there a way to accomplish the gist of what I've got above in C#? Or is it just not possible.

Edit: For a practical example of what this is for, it's a generic communication protocol I use (socket communication). There is a socket wrapper class (OuterClass) and you create a Message class (InnerClass), set a few things in it, and hand it to the socket wrapper, which handles all of the internal stuff. The Message class has some internal data the socket wrapper sets and works with, and I was hoping I could have that in the original class without having to have a different internal class to store it in.

Comment: Carry a large bat and threaten to hit anyone who uses the "internal" member.

Comment: But seriously, I think you can solve this by injecting one type into another. Can you give a realistic example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @jrummell I added a little explanation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want to phrase that "give access to another of my classes, but not to classes outside my assembly".

The simple solution would be to declare the inner class fields as `internal`, instead of private. Your classes in the same assembly can access them, but classes outside cannot.

Comment: You beat me to it by about 5 seconds... :)

Comment: And, as a side note in case you are doing any testing, then you can still test internal with InternalsVisibleTo (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just declare `InnerClass` as `private`. Nobody outside `OuterClass` will be able to access it.

If you want to pass instances around, inherit from a public class or interface, like this:

```
class OuterClass
{
    public abstract class AbstractInnerClass { ... };
    private class InnerClass: AbstractInnerClass { ... };

    public AbstractInnerClass DoStuff(AbstractInnerClass this_class)
    {
        InnerClass real_class = (InnerClass)this_class;
        ... do your stuff ...
    }
}
```

To the outside, only `AbstractInnerClass` exists, and `InnerClass` is merely an implementation detail.